# Radio Button CardView(Lista/RecyclerView)

Tags: android

I have a Recycler View with questions CardView. Each question has 3 radio button (yes, perhaps not) answer. Until then ta everything working, except that;

When we answer the questions. The RadioButtons the following question mark alone. And if we change the responta and return the list alone change the answers of the above questions.

[image]

Thank help ... following code.

---

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class QuizRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizRecyclerViewAdapter.QuizViewHolder> {

Context context;
//
private List<PerguntasQuiz> perguntasQuizList;

//
public QuizRecyclerViewAdapter() {
    this.perguntasQuizList = new PerguntasDAO().listaTodasPerguntasBanco();
}

//
public QuizRecyclerViewAdapter(List<PerguntasQuiz> perguntasQuizList) {
    this.perguntasQuizList = perguntasQuizList;
}

@Override
public QuizViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Desta forma o card view não pega o match_Parent no layout_width
    //View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.perguntas_card_view, null);

    // Assim(false) a view raiz, é usada somente para inflar o outro xml(card_view)
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.perguntas_card_view, parent, false);
    QuizViewHolder quizViewHolder = new QuizViewHolder(view);
    return quizViewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final QuizViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // Recupera as informações na posição em questão.
    final PerguntasQuiz perguntasQuiz = perguntasQuizList.get(position);
    //


    // Modifica o texto na View.
    holder.textViewPerguntas.setText(perguntasQuiz.getPergunta());
    //
    holder.radioButtonSim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            atualizaListaPerguntaQuizResposta(holder.getLayoutPosition(), PerguntasQuiz.RESPOSTA_SIM);

        }
    });

    holder.radioButtonAsVezes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            atualizaListaPerguntaQuizResposta(holder.getLayoutPosition(), PerguntasQuiz.RESPOSTA_AS_VEZES);

        }
    });

    holder.radioButtonNao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            atualizaListaPerguntaQuizResposta(holder.getLayoutPosition(), PerguntasQuiz.RESPOSTA_NAO);
        }
  });
}

public void atualizaListaPerguntaQuizResposta(int posição, int resposta) {

    perguntasQuizList

.get(posição).setResposta(resposta);

    }
public List<PerguntasQuiz> getPerguntasQuizList() {

    return perguntasQuizList;

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    PerguntasQuiz perguntasQuiz = perguntasQuizList.get(position);
    long reposta;

    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return super.equals(o);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int tamanhoLista;
    if (perguntasQuizList == null || perguntasQuizList.isEmpty()) {
        tamanhoLista = 0;
    } else {
        tamanhoLista = this.perguntasQuizList.size();
    }

    return tamanhoLista;
}

public static class QuizViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewPerguntas;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton radioButtonSim;
    private RadioButton radioButtonAsVezes;
    private RadioButton radioButtonNao;


    public QuizViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_radio_group);
        radioButtonSim = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_radio_button_sim);
        radioButtonAsVezes = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_radio_button_as_vezes);
        radioButtonNao = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_radio_button_nao);
        textViewPerguntas = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_id_perguntas_quiz);
        //
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.card_view_radio_button_sim) {
                    radioButtonSim.setChecked(true);
                    group.setTag(checkedId);
                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + getAdapterPosition() + " selecionado SIM");
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.card_view_radio_button_as_vezes) {
                    radioButtonAsVezes.setChecked(true);
                    group.setTag(checkedId);
                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + getAdapterPosition() + " selecionado AS VEZES");
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.card_view_radio_button_nao) {
                    radioButtonNao.setChecked(true);
                              group.setTag(checkedId);
                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + getAdapterPosition() + " selecionado NÃO");
                } else {
                    group.clearCheck();
                }

            }
        });

    }
    }
}
```

Quiz Activity

```
public class QuizEmocionalActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private AdView adView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    QuizRecyclerViewAdapter quizRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_emocional);
        //
        // Admob
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_activity_admob);
        adView.setAdListener(new ToastListener(this));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.quiz_emocional_recycle_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        //
        //  List<PerguntasQuiz> perguntasQuizList =  perguntasDAO.listaTodasPerguntasBanco();
        this.quizRecyclerViewAdapter = new QuizRecyclerViewAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(quizRecyclerViewAdapter);

    }


    public void onClickSalvarQuiz(View view) {
        List<PerguntasQuiz> perguntasQuizList = quizRecyclerViewAdapter.getPerguntasQuizList();
        int pontuacao = 0;
        boolean ok = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < perguntasQuizList.size(); i++) {
            if (perguntasQuizList.get(i).getResposta() == -1) {
                alertRespostasQuiz(i + 1);
                ok = false;
                break;
            } else {
                pontuacao += perguntasQuizList.get(i).getResposta();
            }
        }

        if (ok == true) {
            // salva Quiz
            chamaSalvarQuiz(pontuacao);
            // passa e mostra resultado em ResultadoQuizActivity
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("pontuacao", String.valueOf(pontuacao));
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultadoQuizActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    //
    public boolean chamaSalvarQuiz(int percResultado) {
        boolean ok = true;

        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        QuizDAO quizDAO = new QuizDAO();
        //
        quiz.setPercResultado(percResultado);
        quiz.setDataQuiz(new Date());
        //
        ok = quizDAO.salvarQuiz(quiz);
        //
        return ok;
    }

    //
    public void alertRespostasQuiz(int pontuacao) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizEmocionalActivity.this);
        //
        String mensagem = getString(R.string.texto_item_nao_respondido_quiz_activity) + " \""
                + pontuacao + "\" " + getString(R.string.texto_nao_respondido_quiz_activity);
        String responder = this.getString(R.string.texto_alert_responder_quiz);
        //
        builder.setMessage(mensagem);
        //
        builder.setNeutralButton(responder, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        //
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    public void onClickZoomMenos(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_quiz_mocional_zoom_menos);
        button.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

    }

    public void onClickZoomMais(View view) {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.card_view_radio_button_sim);
        if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Zoom mais clicado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somebody help?!

Comment: Somebody help?!